# How do you update state of the parent component from a child component when an event takes place in the parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have to update state of the parent class component from child functional component only when a click event takes place in the parent component. Right now I've access of the data from child to parent component but when I update the state I get error, maximum depth reached. So I thought it'd be better to update the parent's state from child only when the certain event takes place in the parent component but I'm unable to find any approach. Could you please show some light?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured out a way to achieve it.

Step 1: Set a boolean for your event taking place in your parent state using useState hook.

```
// Inside Parent component
const [eventInParent, setEventInParent] = React.useState(false);
```

Step 2: pass the eventInParent as prop to your child component

// Inside Child component

Step 3: Receive the event status (eventInParent) in your child component in your props and use it as a dependency in useEffect hook

```
React.useEffect(() => {

 if(eventInParent) {
   
 }
 
}, [eventInParent]);
```

As you can see every time event will hit in parent component the eventInParent value will change which will trigger the useEffect hook in the child component.

Answer (score 1):

From your description, the best thing to do is to [lift state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper) from the child to the parent so that the information you currently only have in the child is available in the parent (which can provide it to the child as a prop). Then, the child isn't involved in this at all, the event in the parent updates the parent's state, which is standard.

But if you absolutely can't do that:

It's taking you off the beaten path, but you could:

1. Have the parent pass the child two things:

   1. a means of subscribing to an event from the parent
   2. a function to call to update the  parent's state
2. Have the child subscribe to the event
3. Have the parent raise the event the child subscribes to when the click occurs
4. Have the child respond to that event by calling the function from (1)(2) above

While that would *work*, it's a bit convoluted. So again, if you can avoid it, move the state needed for the update from the child to the parent and keep the entire update in the parent.

Comment: I've legacy parent component and a legacy project. The child component has been created to keep away from legacy, so I don't intend to lift state up, because we're going to need the state of this child component in many other places and we don't want to involve with parent legacy component.

Comment: The off the beaten path that you suggested seems more reliable in my scenario but the problem is how do I subscribe the event from parent to child, I've never done this before. Do you have any suggestion?